# How do I read data from the control in Word Document usng Open XML

Tags: c#, ms-word, openxml

I am writing a code in C# using **Open XML SDK 2.0.** I have defined some controls in **Word document** like TextBox, Select Option etc. I want to read their data programatically (sample given below)..

```
WordprocessingDocument InputWordDocument = WordprocessingDocument.Open(@"C:\Users\jayant\Desktop\Template.docx", false);
foreach (Control ctrl in InputWordDocument.MainDocumentPart.Document.Body.Descendants<Control>())
{
    Console.WriteLine(ctrl.Name.Value);
}
```

But it shows the name of the controls not their values.

How do I get thevalues?

Answer (score 2):

You have to use the DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Wordprocessing.Control class not the System.Windows.Forms.Control class!
Change that afterwards you have to go througth the childnodes.

```
WordprocessingDocument InputWordDocument = WordprocessingDocument.Open(@"C:\Users\jayant\Desktop\Template.docx", false);
foreach (DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Wordprocessing.Control ctrl in InputWordDocument.MainDocumentPart.Document.Body.Descendants<Control>())
{
    ...
}
```

Hint: Use XmlNode it is easier to handle.

Comment: Nothing works.. actually I have compared two docx files using Open XML Productivity tool such that one file having control without data and other having control with data.. but no data was found during comparison :(

Comment: I am using XmlNode to read the word files, you should try it too.
And now i see the problem ... 
You are using System.Windows.Forms.Controls not the controls from openxml!

Comment: no.. Because when I print ctrl.Name, it prints the controls name of the word file

Comment: Ok, the last thing i could tell you is, try it with XMLNode!

Comment: Can you please provide me a code snippet? If possible then it will be great thing :)

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/bb656295%28v=office.12%29.aspx try this one, it helped me alot.

Answer (score 1):

You have to use ctrl.Id to get the relationship id instead of ctrl.Name. You need this relationship id in order to access the control contents which are stored elsewhere.

Afterwards, you may call MainDocumentPart.GetPartById(ctrl.Id) and get the control data. Before using anything, remember that you have to cast it to the correct type.